# Is there anything that ignore the error lines and execute whole code and generate the output automatically

Tags: error-handling

Consider, I have a code which give the output. If there are some lines of codes in between the code. those lines can't alter the output.
In this case, Is there anything that ignore the error lines and execute whole code and generate the output automatically.

Awaiting for the response.

Comment: What language is it? Also you can just comment them out, or wrap them in `try {} catch (e) {}`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.